# Chrome starts download instead of displaying webpage from local server

Tags: server, apache2

I set up Apache web server.

When I open `http://localhost` in Google Chrome, it asks me to download a file. It works correctly with Firefox.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please specify what file type it is chrome is downloading?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Going to "http://localhost:8888/folder" triggers a download (extensionless file name 'download'). It's a php file, but it's processed, so php works properly.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your server is sending a Content-Type header that Chrome thinks it should download, rather than display.

You can check for this with:

`wget --server-response -O /dev/null http://localhost/`

which should display the headers that the server is sending.

Comment: my output is --2011-03-03 17:42:47--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
**/*something*/**
  Content-Type: text/html
Length: 517 [text/html]
Saving to: `/dev/null'

100%[======================================>] 517         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2011-03-03 17:42:47 (59.8 MB/s) - `/dev/null' saved [517/517]

Comment: The /* something */ may provide a clue too; could you edit your question and add this info?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably needing to install php or it is not running at the time that you wish to open a PHP file.

If this is the case, first make sure everything is OK in your PHP config by running the next in a php file which you can name `info.php` and calling it like `localhost/info.php` when placed in your localhost root folder, usually `/var/www`

### info.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title> PHP Test Script </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
phpinfo( );
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The result should be like this:

[image]

If you are receiving issues in your php config you first try to fix it, and if you receive an info.php file download then you should first install php support in your system, which can easily be achieved via synaptic.

Comment: hey thanks that helped, but still when i type http://localhost/index.html my page gets opened in chromium and firefox but if i type only localhost it asks me to download a file named download, this is not the case with firefox

Comment: Do you mind posting the contents of your index.html in order to see if it is pointing to a file download instead of the execution of html code? Additionally, check file permissions in order to see if it is having 755, which may affect the behavior of your index.html file.